# Power Query, M language, Count items in a row with Special condition

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to count specific items in a row,

**EDITED:**

Sample Table

| Column Name | Foreign key 1 | Foreign key 2 | Foreign key 3 | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 | Column 7 | Column 8 | Column 9 | Column 10 | Column 11 | Column 12 | Column 13 | Column 14 | Column 15 | Column 16 | Column 17 | Column 18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Identifier 1 | Foreign Key 1.1 | Foreign Key 2.1 | Foreign Key 3.1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 |
| Identifier 2 | Foreign Key 1.2 | Foreign Key 2.2 | Foreign Key 3.2 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 2 |
| Identifier 3 | Foreign Key 1.3 | Foreign Key 2.3 | Foreign Key 3.3 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 4 | Type 4 | Type 4 |
| Identifier 4 | Foreign Key 1.4 | Foreign Key 2.4 | Foreign Key 3.4 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 4 | Type 4 | Type 1 |
| Identifier 5 | Foreign Key 1. | Foreign Key 2.5 | Foreign Key 3.5 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 4 | Type 4 |

The code I am using for the same is as follows,

**EDITED:**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column Name", type text}, {"Foreign Key 1", type text}, {"Foreign Key 2", type text}, {"Foreign Key 3", Int64.Type}, {"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type any}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}, {"Column10", type text}, {"Column11", type text}, {"Column12", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column Name", "Foreign Key 1", "Foreign Key 2", "Foreign Key 3"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),

 #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Column Name"}, {      
 
     {"Type 1", (t)=> Text.From(List.Count(List.Select(t[Value],each _ = "Type 1"))) & " days"},
     {"Type 2", (t)=> Text.From(List.Count(List.Select(t[Value],each _ = "Type 2"))) & " days"},
     {"Type 3", (t)=> Text.From(List.Count(List.Select(t[Value],each _ = "Type 3"))) & " days"},
     {"Type 4", (t)=> Text.From(List.Count(List.Select(t[Value],each _ = "Type 4"))) & " days"}
     })
    in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

The Result for the same would be

| Column Name | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3 | Type 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Identifier 1 | 10 days | 3 days | 5 days | 0 days |
| Identifier 2 | 14 days | 4 days | 0 days | 0 days |
| Identifier 3 | 5 days | 5 days | 5 days | 3 days |
| Identifier 4 | 10 days | 3 days | 3 days | 2 days |
| Identifier 5 | 6 days | 4 days | 6 days | 2 days |

The problem with this it gives the count of all Type 1 cells in the row.
Is there any possibility/way of getting the count of each type based on the last occurrence of the type in the row???

For eg consider the same table row 1

| Column Name | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 | Column 7 | Column 8 | Column 9 | Column 10 | Column 11 | Column 12 | Column 13 | Column 14 | Column 15 | Column 16 | Column 17 | Column 18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Identifier 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 2 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 3 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 | Type 1 |

Here Type 1 gets repeated 2 times or in 2 batches, is there any way to consider only the last batch that gets repeated and the number of times it gets repeated there??

the result should be like this

| Column Name | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3 | Type 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Identifier 1 | 5 days | 3 days | 5 days | 0 days |

How can I go about this??

Comment: How did your other question go? Perhaps accept an answer on that one first...

Comment: @SolarMike, I am trying Gonso's solution, but the issue is there is no guaranteed replication of the error.  It crashes rarely.  am waiting for it to crash but in the 10 runs so far with same data set it hasn't crashed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with various groupings.

I used a **custom function** for each subgroup.
Please read the comments in the code to understand the algorithm

**main M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    
//group by identifier to make a table from each row
//then feed each subtable to the custom function
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Identifier"}, {
        {"Count", each fnLastGroupCount(_), type table}}),

//expand the table
    #"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", 
        {"Column1", "lastGroupCount"}, {"Column1", "lastGroupCount"}),
    
//Pivot with no aggregation
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Count", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Count"[Column1]), "Column1", "lastGroupCount")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

***Custom Function***
*be sure to rename as shown in the code*

```
//Be sure to rename this query "fnLastGroupCount"

(Source as table) =>
let 
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(Source),

//Add a shifted row as this is a MUCH faster way to refer to previous row than using the {[Index]-1} method
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Transposed Table",1),
    shiftedList = {null} & List.RemoveLastN(Table.Column(#"Removed Top Rows","Column1"),1),
    custom1 = Table.ToColumns(#"Removed Top Rows") & {shiftedList},
    custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Top Rows") & {"Previous Row"}),

//Add Index column which we will use to separate the different groups of types
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(custom2, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//if the current row is not the same as the previous row, then return the Index, otherwise a null
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Group", each if [Column1] = [Previous Row] then null else [Index]),

//Fill down the group column so all in the same consecutive sequence will have the same "number"
//then remove the Index column
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Group"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Down",{"Previous Row", "Index"}),

//Get count for each Type and Group
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Column1", "Group"}, {
        {"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}
        }),

//Group again by ID and get the last group by returning the last associated count
    #"Grouped Rows2" = Table.Group(#"Grouped Rows1", {"Column1"}, {
        {"lastGroupCount", each List.Last([Count]),Int64.Type}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows2"
```

**Results from your posted data**
[image]

***Note: if the above works, it is trivial to modify it to add "days" and "zero's" to the table***

## Edit

*Having reviewed your uploaded file, I make the following comments:*

- Your real data has 10 columns that need to be deleted before hand
- Your real data has empty entries in many cells

  - These empties get converted to *`null`* when used as the Source, so need special handling:
  - in this case, we can just filter them out after expanding the Grouped table
- You did **NOT** copy the **custom function** as written. You wound up changing it from a custom function to just a query.  This will not work.

1. Copy/paste the custom function **AS WRITTEN**.  Do **NOT** modify it (except be sure to rename it as instructed)
2. Below is rewritten **Main Code** which

   - deletes the unneeded column
   - filters out the nulls
   - As a bonus, I added the transforms to list the results as `n day` or `n days`

*Note also that if you want the output columns to appear in a specific, non-alphabetic order, you can hard code that*

**Revised Main Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//remove unneeded columns (columns 2-11, but note 1,10 since count is zero-based)
remColsList = List.Range(Table.ColumnNames(Source), 1,10),
remCols = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,remColsList),
    
//group by identifier to make a table from each row
//then feed each subtable to the custom function
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(remCols, {"Bag No"}, {
        {"Count", each fnLastGroupCount(_), type table}}),

//expand the table
    #"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", 
        {"Column1", "lastGroupCount"}, {"Column1", "lastGroupCount"}),
//Remove 'null' rows
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Count", each ([Column1] <> null)),
    
//Pivot with no aggregation
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Filtered Rows", List.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"[Column1]), "Column1", "lastGroupCount"),

//Type columns as text
    textTransforms= List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"), each {_, Text.Type}),
    typeText = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column", textTransforms), 

//add "day" or "days" or replace null with "0 days"
    transformOps = List.Accumulate(
        List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(typeText),1),
        {},
        (state,current)=> if state = {} then  
            {{current, each if _ = null then "0 days" 
                else if _ = "1" then "1 day" 
                else _ & " days"}} else 
            state & 
                {{current, each if _ = null then "0 days" 
                else if _ = "1" then "1 day" 
                else _ & " days"}}),
    transformCols = Table.TransformColumns(typeText,transformOps)
in
    transformCols
```

**Screenshot of a *portion* of the output table**
[image]

Comment: so if i need to apply this logic to all the Types (Type 1,Type 2,Type 3,Type 4) how will i go about that?

Comment: @AllwynP I don't understand your question.  As you can see from the example, all of your types are represented in the output.  Is your sample data not representative?  What happened when you tried?  What types were missing?

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld, am able to get fnLastGroupCount to run, but the Main M Code am getting the error "unable to covert value of type table to value of type function"

Comment: @AllwynP How did you run the function without running the main code? What step in the main code is returning the error (look at the Applied Steps for the main query)

Comment: I understand the confusion, i am editing the question, it will include the full code and sample data set. Please look into this.  the error is occurring at Expanded count.

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld, I have edited the query to include my full code

Comment: @AllwynP Do you want the `Foreign key` columns to not show in the results? Will there always be three columns of them? If not, will the header for those columns always be named as you show?

Comment: I dont want Foreign Key column to show in the result, there will be 9 columns of them, headers are named as such [primary key/column name -> Bag No], [Foreign Key -> Parent Bag,Old Variant Name,Bag Qty,WC,WC1,Order Category,Order Number,Age,BC  Date,Dispatched] , [Column1/Column2 etc -> would be 1st July, 2nd July ..] @Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: Is it possible to share a file with you? it would clear out the confusion

Comment: and Type 1 to type 4 they represent upto 14 different formats that can appear throughout the row. @Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: @AllwynP upload as xlsx to some sharing site, and post link here

Comment: @AllwynP And by the way, my code runs without any errors on your edited sample data base. Of course those foreign keys are represented, but that's just a matter of removing columns at the start. Something about your implementation, or something you are not showing in your data.  Your edited code does not show any similarity to what I suggested.

Comment: @AllwynP I have edited my response and commented on the errors.

Comment: the code works beautifully.. thanks 

Comment: @AllwynP I think the error message is self-explanatory. Did you look for that error value in your data?

Comment: sorry ron.. that was not worth ur time..  i missed one when i cleaned the data.. and i was too confident that it could not be an error value issue

Comment: @AllwynP NP. When using Excel as a data source, PQ will stumble on error values in the data. Sometimes cleaning the data is the best solution; sometimes replacing them in PQ is best. All depends on the situation.